# Subdomain map to sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, virtualhost, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-html

I have a web application which needs to have dynamic subdomain for each company. And the site has SSL too. I am using apache on Ubuntu VPS. What I did was I made virtualhost settings like below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    ..........
    .................
</VirtualHost>
```

directing the traffic to SSL is ok.

So What I need to do now is I have a folder "/app" in my web root. I want all the sub domains to direct to that particular folder and show the same url on the address bar.

I have enabled http_proxy module in php and made this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/app/$1 [P,NC,QSA]
```

When I visit "https://test.domain.com" this redirects it to "https://domain.com/app/index.php". I know why it is happening because when the htaccess redirect happens to "http://domain.com/app/index.php" my virtualhost configuration sees a non-SSL request and it redirects the request to same address with SSL. So I changed the .htaccess to this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/app/$1 [P,NC,QSA]
```

I put "https" in the rewrite rule. when again I visit the "https://test.domain.com" it gave me this error.

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was     
unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to 
inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you 
performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error 
log.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at kjdcndkj.domain.com Port 443
```

Finally what I want is

```
1) redirect any Non-SSL trafic to SSL
2) any *.domain.com to /app folder
```

Can some one help me on this

Thank you.

Comment: Can someone help me on this please :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No the folder should be always /app so I would put this and check

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-]+)\.domain\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app/$1 [L]